# Creating a note system for an IRC bot

Tags: java

So I am making an IRC bot and I want to be able to create a system for users to input notes using "!note " and later be reminded using "!remind ".

I had the idea for a HashMap, using this code:

```
public HashMap notes = new HashMap();

if (message.startsWith("!note ")) {
    notes.put(sender.toLowerCase(), message.substring(6));
    sendMessage(channel, "Note recorded.");
}
if (message.startsWith("!remind ")) {
    String nick = message.substring(8);
    String remind = (String) notes.get(nick.toLowerCase());
    sendMessage(channel, remind);
}
```

But this will only allow one note per user since a HashMap contains no duplicates.

What's a better to let users store more than one note?

Comment: Why not just `HashMap<String, List<String>>`?

Comment: Multimap sounds reasonable http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: @ug_ The user can only add one item at a time, so that's why I have `HashMap<String, String>`. If I try to change it to `HashMap<String, List<String>>` then I get the error String cannot be converted to List<String>. Is there a way to work around that? Excuse me as I'm new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply store a list of strings instead of a single string.

```
public HashMap<String, List<String>> userNotesStore = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

/**
 * Adds a note to the users list of notes.
 * @param username
 * @param note
 */
private void addNote(String username, String note) {
    List<String> notes = userNotesStore.get(username);
    if(notes == null) {
        notes = new ArrayList<String>();
        userNotesStore.put(username, notes);
    }
    notes.add(note);
}
```

then using your existing code you can modify it as such

```
if (message.startsWith("!note ")) {
    addNote(sender.toLowerCase(), message.substring(6));
    sendMessage(channel, "Note recorded.");
}
if (message.startsWith("!remind ")) {
    String nick = message.substring(8);
    List<String> notes = userNotesStore.get(nick);
    if(notes != null) {
        // send all notes to the user.
        for(String note : notes) {
            sendMessage(channel, note);
        }
    } else {
        // send no notes message?
        sendMessage(channel, "*You have no notes recorded.");
    }
}
```